# Function Decipherer

Tags: java

I'm a nooby on Java and in programmation too that's why I'm learning it :) I need your help for an exercise. I need to create the function decipherer with some changes on my arg.

```
import java.util.StringBuffer;

public class Decipherer{

    String arg ="aopi?sedohtém@#?sedhtmg+p9l!";

    int nbrChar = arg.length()/2;

    String arg2 = arg.substring(5, nbrChar-1);

    String arg3 = arg2.replace("@#?", " ");

    String arg4 = new StringBuilder(arg3).reverse().toString();

    return arg4;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Decipherer mesage1 = new Decipherer("0@sn9sirppa@#?ia'jgtvryko1");
    Decipherer message3 = new Decipherer("q8e?wsellecif@#?sel@#?setuotpazdsy0*b9+mw@x1vj");
    Decipherer message4 = new Decipherer("aopi?sedohtém@#?sedhtmg+p9l!");

}
```

--

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
>           The constructor Decipherer(String) is undefined
>           The constructor Decipherer(String) is undefined
>           The constructor Decipherer(String) is undefined
>           Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody

```
    at Decipherer.main(Decipherer.java:24)
```

I don't understand why it ask another "}". Could someone explain to me please?

Comment: You are calling a constructor in your code with a string but you have no such constructor in your class instead you it seems you think you can make method calls directly at the class level. Create a constructor `public Decipherer(String value) {...}` and move your member initialisation code inside it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main method must be within a class. You could put it e.g. in `Decipherer`. In addition the operations that you are doing must be put inside a method to be able to **return** something. And you need a constructor accepting a `String`, e.g.

```
public class Decipherer {

  private final String input;

  // constructor accepting String
  public Decipherer(String input) {
    this.input = input;
  }

  public String decipher() {

    int nbrChar = input.length() / 2;

    String arg2 = input.substring(5, nbrChar - 1);

    String arg3 = arg2.replace("@#?", " ");

    return new StringBuilder(arg3).reverse().toString();
  }

  // main method inside class
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Decipherer decipherer1 = new Decipherer("0@sn9sirppa@#?ia'jgtvryko1");
    String message1 = decipherer1.decipher();
    Decipherer decipherer2 = new Decipherer("q8e?wsellecif@#?sel@#?setuotpazdsy0*b9+mw@x1vj");
    Decipherer decipherer3 = new Decipherer("aopi?sedohtém@#?sedhtmg+p9l!");
  }
}
```

By executing `new Decipherer("0@sn9sirppa@#?ia'jgtvryko1");` an object of type `Decipherer` is created with field `input`. You can then invoke method `decipher()` on this object.

Alternatively you can also go without constructor and expose a **static** method to decipher, e.g.

```
public static String decipher(String input) {
    int nbrChar = input.length() / 2;
    String arg2 = input.substring(5, nbrChar - 1);
    String arg3 = arg2.replace("@#?", " ");
    return new StringBuilder(arg3).reverse().toString();
  }
```

which you can call in your main method as `final String message = Decipherer.decipher("0@sn9sirppa@#?ia'jgtvryko1");`.